# Apache Redirect Loop on Drupal Installation in VHost SubDirectory on Root URL only

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, httpd.conf, rhel7

I am currently having an issue with our Production site Home Page of a Drupal installation failing with "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

A little background to our set up:
On our server, we have different VHosts set up to run different applications.

The Idea is that each installation will be served at a subdirectory of the the domain name, such as subdomain.example.com/app1 and subdomain.example.com/app2.

It's been running for almost a year and all of a sudden, only the home page of the Drupal installation starts doing redirect loops (subdomain.example.com/app). Staging environment is set up the exact same way and does not exhibit this behavior. Also, other pages within the production application are served without any issues (subdomain.example.com/app/page).

The installation is located on the server at /var/www/app. This should serve as the document root for the installation when visited at subdomain.example.com/app/.

The VHOST for the troubled installation looks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/app">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    Include /var/www/app/.htaccess
</Directory>
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerPath /app
DocumentRoot /var/www/app
</VirtualHost>
# Set the Alias for the CLP installation
Alias "/app/" "/var/www/app/"
Alias "/app" "/var/www/app"
```

I also have a .htaccess file inside each of the VHOSTS to drive redirection:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
# Relative to the DocumentRoot defined in httpd.conf
ErrorDocument 404 /app/index.php

# Set the default handler.
# Relative to the DocumentRoot defined in httpd.conf
DirectoryIndex /app/index.php /app/index.html /app/index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value memory_limit 500M
# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
    php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
    php_flag register_globals                 off
    php_flag session.auto_start               off
    php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
    php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
    php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations.
    ExpiresActive On

    # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
    ExpiresDefault A1209600

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
        # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
        # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
        # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
        # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
ExpiresActive Off
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
    # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
    # you don't bounce between http and https.
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

    # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
    # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
    # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
    # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
    # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
    # above.
    #
    # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
    # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
    # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
    #
    # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
    # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
    # downloaded.
    RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]

    # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
    # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
    # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
    #
    # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
    # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
    # uncomment the following:
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    #
    # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
    # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
    # uncomment the following:
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
    # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
    # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
    # modify the following line:
    RewriteBase /app/
    #
    # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
    # uncomment the following line:
    #RewriteBase /

    # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
    # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
    # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

# Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

# Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

<FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
  # Serve correct encoding type.
  Header set Content-Encoding gzip
  # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
  Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch ^(.*)/app/course-page/CP([0-9]*)$ $1/app/course-page/$2
RedirectMatch ^(.*)/app/ramping-site/RS([0-9]*)$ $1/app/ramping-site/$2
RedirectMatch ^(.*)/app/content/BCTID([0-9]*)$ $1/app/content/$2
</IfModule>

# Add headers to all responses.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

Going on two days with service down and I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: Set `RewriteLogLevel 2` or `RewriteLogLevel 3`, and look in the `RewriteLog` to help you see where the loop is coming from.

Comment: I have attempted to follow the instructions from https://serverfault.com/questions/11332/troubleshooting-apache-redirects-in-production but it is not writing anything to the logs specified.

Do the logs need to be in a specific location or have the parent folders set with certain permissions?

Comment: Just writeable by Apache. If you put the rewrite log in the same directory as the access and error logs, it shouldn't be an issue. Did you reload the server config after you set the RewriteLogLevel?

Comment: The rewrite is most likely coming from your Drupal, please check its settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input. It turned out to be a corrupted file on the VM that eventually caused it to crash. Still not sure what it was.

If I am able to figure out what actually got corrupted I will put it out here for reference.

However, prior to crashing, Apache (HTTPD) stop running PHP 7.0 in the browser. It would run PHP scripts in the CLI, but would just show the PHP text in web browsers. A few hours later the server crashed.